# spring cloud gateway exception Illegal character in authority at index error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to setup spring cloud gateway for a api, but seeing an illegal argument exception with the route uri. Any help is appreciated.

Running this app on Ubuntu and I got the same exception with both Spring boot 2.1.4 and 2.1.5.

This is how configured my application.properties file in the gateway app.

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name= api-gateway
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=reporting-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://reporting-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/reporting/**
```

This is the exception that I see.

```
2019-06-06 09:56:17.304  WARN 4561 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initializ                                                ation - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration';                                                 nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at in                                                dex 5: lb://REPORTING-SERVICE
2019-06-06 09:56:17.316  INFO 4561 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2019-06-06 09:56:20.317  INFO 4561 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2019-06-06 09:56:20.324  INFO 4561 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/apitest.****.*****.com:api-gateway:8080 - deregister  status: 200
2019-06-06 09:56:20.342  INFO 4561 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
2019-06-06 09:56:20.353  INFO 4561 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-06 09:56:20.365 ERROR 4561 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is reactor.core.Ex                                                ceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 5: lb://REPORTING-SERVICE
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEAS                                                E.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELE                                                ASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context                                                -5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.REL                                                EASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELE                                                ASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) ~[spring-context-5.1.                                                6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.jav                                                a:121) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELE                                                ASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:67)                                                 ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: that's the issue

Comment: Thanks for the help but my build failed with this error after making the change.
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
Description:
Binding to target [Bindable@330c1f61 type = java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.predicate.PredicateDefinition>, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty(message={javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}, groups=[], payload=[]), @javax.validation.Valid()]] failed:
Property: spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].path
Value: /api/reporting/**

Comment: This is what I see in the error message.
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates' to java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.predicate.PredicateDefinition>
 Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.UnboundConfigurationPropertiesException: The elements [spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].path] were left unbound.

Comment: my bad i missed, change it to this```spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates=Path=/api/reporting/**```

Answer (score 2):

Fix the property:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates=Path=/api/reporting/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://reporting-service
```

Reference: [issue-56480485](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/issue-56480485-spring-cloud-gateway-issue)

Comment: I still get the same error. 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 5: lb://REPORTING-SERVICE

Comment: remove the unwanted spaces and try ```spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://reporting-service```

Comment: Removed the spaces but it didn't help

Comment: Do I need to setup some load balancer for this to work?

Comment: @Sam I dont see any issue, I am able to load successfully. take a look here [issue-56480485](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/issue-56480485-spring-cloud-gateway-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the property by adding the [index of service] for predicates

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/reporting/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://reporting-service
```

But make sure the reporting-service which you are adding here is the same name as the name declared in your eureka server

Comment: wrap the code snippet with a code block

Comment: @NipunaJayawardana You can suggest an edit in the future, but this time I fixed it.